# How to use Anaconda with gcc instead of clang

Tags: python, python-3.x

How can I change the compiler that is used for compiling the Python binaries?

I have Anaconda on my Mac (macOS 10.13) but it uses clang instead of gcc-mp-6 that I neeed.

Comment: It probably don't matter. Both GCC & Clang having the same ABI (what might matter more is version of ABI)

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding your question.  Are you asking how to install GCC under Conda?  Or how to build Conda packages using GCC that other people will then install?

Comment: Anaconda says: [GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Clang 4.0.1 (tags/RELEASE_401/final)]. I would like to change it to gcc-mp-6